# Iteration: Powershell Output

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am having trouble getting the right PowerShell output.

> > ## An example of the Output is as follows:
> >
> > ComputerName | Drive | Size | Free | PercentFree
> >     COMP-NAME         H:      249    11      4.5
> >
> > > ComputerName | Drive | Size | Free | PercentFree
> > >       COMP-NAME       C:       67    3.2       4.7
> > >
> > > ComputerName | Drive | Size | Free | PercentFree
> > >       COMP-NAME       H:     249    11       4.5
> > >
> > > ComputerName | Drive | Size | Free | PercentFree
> > >       COMP-NAME       C:     67    3.2       4.7
> > >
> > > ComputerName | Drive | Size | Free | PercentFree
> > >       COMP-NAME       H:      249    11       4.5
> > >
> > > ComputerName | Drive | Size | Free | PercentFree
> > >       COMP-NAME       C:      67    3.2       4.7
> > >
> > > ComputerName | Drive | Size | Free | PercentFree
> > >       COMP-NAME       H:      249    11       4.5
> > >
> > > ComputerName | Drive | Size | Free | PercentFree
> > >       COMP-NAME       C:      67    3.2       4.7

The Script below queries the host for low disk below certain threshold and send it to the appropriate email. The Script runs fine, but I keep getting repeated lines.

Can someone please help? Thank you.

```
#THE SCRIPT

# Set Global Parameters
$emailTO = "email@email.com"
$emailFrom = "LowSpaceNotify@email.com"
$smtpServer = "X.X.X.X"

$computers = "COMP-NAME"
$i = 0

# Get Drive Data
$report = @(
foreach($computer in $computers)
{
$drives = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3}
     foreach($drive in $drives)
     {
          # Calculate Free Space
          $obj = new-object psobject -Property @{
               ComputerName = $computer
               Drive = $drive.DeviceID
               Size = $drive.size / 1GB
               Free = $drive.freespace / 1GB
               PercentFree = $drive.freespace / $drive.size * 100
               }
          # Monitor for 10% or less in free space and report accordingly
          if ($obj.PercentFree -lt 10) {
               $obj | Format-Table ComputerName,Drive,@{n='Size';e={'{0:N1}' -f $_.Size}},@{n='Free';e={'{0:N1}' -f $_.Free}},@{n='PercentFree';e={'{0:N1}' -f $_.PercentFree}} | Out-String
               $i++
               }
     }

}
)

# Send notification if script finds more than 0 drives with less than 10% free space
if ($i -gt 0)
   {
       foreach ($user in $emailTo)
                {
        echo "Sending Email Notification to $user"
        $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
        $subject = "Server with Low Disk Space"
        foreach ($line in $report)
            {
                $body += "$line "
                }
        Send-MailMessage -to $user -From $emailFrom -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Subject $Subject -Body $body
                }
   }
```

Comment: What is `foreach ($line in $report)` supposed to be iterating through?  You don't have `$report` assigned to anything.  And the closing parenthesis before the `# Send notification...` comment is not paired with anything.  A working MCVE would help you get an answer much more quickly.

Comment: It looks like report is assigned higher up in the script to all the output in the foreach ($computer in $computers) loop, which is a bit strange but should work fine.  

not sure what you mean by "repeated lines" can you show an example of the output that you are currently getting?

Comment: Hi Tony, the $report is assigned, as Mike said.

Comment: Mike, the repeated lines were provided before the script. They are preceded with the "An example of the Output is as follows:" sentence. Basically, it should be 2 lines, but these lines get repeated 4 times, which seems very strange to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    $ComputerName,
    $EmailTo = "email@email.com",
    $EmailFrom = "LowSpaceNotify@email.com",
    $EmailSubject = 'Low Hard Disk Report',
    $SmtpServer = "X.X.X.X"
)

# Get Drive Data
$DATA = foreach ( $computer in $ComputerName ) {
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object { ( $_.DriveType ) -eq 3 -and ( ( $_.freespace / $_.size ) -lt .1  ) } | ForEach-Object -Process {
        [pscustomobject] @{
            ComputerName = $computer
            Drive        = $_.DeviceID
            Size         = '{0:N1}' -f ( $_.Size / 1GB )
            Free         = '{0:N1}' -f ( $_.freespace / 1GB )
            PercentFree  = '{0:N1}' -f ( $_.freespace / $_.size * 100 )
        }
     }
}

if ( $DATA ) {
    $HTMLBody = $Data | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
    Send-MailMessage -To $EmailTo -From $EmailFrom -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Subject $EmailSubject -Body ( $HTMLBody -Join '`n' ) -BodyAsHtml
}
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks very much for your help. However, the error "..Cannot Convert 'System.Object[]'... " came up as the output. When I removed  "| ConvertTo-Html -Fragment" and  "-BodyAsHtml"  from the script, I was able to get the right non-repeated output. Thanks.

Comment: You caught me. The -Body parameter wants a single string and I was passing in an array of strings. So I updated the script to join $HTMLBody with an escaped new line character. You can do what you did, but mine formats them into a nicely formatted HTML report.

Comment: I like high numbers. Can you mark mine as an answer, please? :)

Comment: I have rated you, Shawn. Thanks again!