# PowerShell Drive Size

Tags: powershell, disk

I have found this idea how to get [drive size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38398788/9671592)

I'm having problem incorporating it to my script as I don't know where to insert the code.
Also the idea is to have only one line per computer outputted even when multi hard drive system exists.

This is the code I'm working with it includes the "Get Drive Data" code

```
# Output file location to be changed as needed
$file="C:\scripts\reports\InentoryTest_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv"
$txt="c:\scripts\reports\InentoryTest-error_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).txt"

# Getting computers from Active Directory
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like 'M416*'} | select -expand name

  Foreach($Computer in $Computers){

if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
 {
 write-host "Cannot reach $Computer is offline" -ForegroundColor red
 }
 else
 {

$Output = @()

    Try
    {
       # Get Drive Data 
       $disk   = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object { ( $_.DriveType ) -eq 3 -and ( ( $_.freespace / $_.size ) -lt .1  ) } | ForEach-Object -Process {
                   [pscustomobject] @{
        Drive        = $_.DeviceID
        Size         = '{0:N1}' -f ( $_.Size / 1GB )
        Free         = '{0:N1}' -f ( $_.freespace / 1GB )
        PercentFree  = '{0:N1}' -f ( $_.freespace / $_.size * 100 )
                        }
                    } 
        $domain = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
        $os   = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
        $mac  = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='True'" -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
        $bios = Get-WmiObject win32_bios -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
        $cpu  = Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
        $AD   = Get-ADComputer $Computer -properties Name,Lastlogondate,ipv4Address,enabled,description,DistinguishedName -ErrorAction Stop
        $ram  = "{0} GB" -f ((Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop | Measure-Object Capacity  -Sum).Sum / 1GB)
        $pc   = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop | select @{Name = "Type";Expression = {if (($_.pcsystemtype -eq '2')  )
                {'Laptop'} Else {'Desktop Or Other'}}
        },Manufacturer,@{Name = "Model";Expression = {if (($_.model -eq "$null")  ) {'Virtual'} Else {$_.model}}},username

        # Create Output
        $data = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            SerialNumber              = $bios.serialnumber -replace "-.*"
            Computername              = $AD.name
            IPaddress                 = $AD.ipv4Address
            MACaddress                = $mac.MACAddress
            Enabled                   = $AD.Enabled
            Description               = $AD.description
            OU                        = $AD.DistinguishedName.split(',')[1].split('=')[1] 
            DC                        = $domain.domain
            Type                      = $pc.type
            Manufacturer              = $pc.Manufacturer
            Model                     = $pc.Model
            RAM                       = $ram
            Disk                      = $disk #Get Drive Data
            ProcessorName             = ($cpu.name | Out-String).Trim()
            NumberOfCores             = ($cpu.NumberOfCores | Out-String).Trim()
            NumberOfLogicalProcessors = ($cpu.NumberOfLogicalProcessors | Out-String).Trim()
            Addresswidth              = ($cpu.Addresswidth | Out-String).Trim()
            OperatingSystem           = $os.caption
            InstallDate               = ([WMI] '').ConvertToDateTime($os.installDate)
            LastLogonDate             = $ld.lastlogondate
            LoggedinUser              = $pc.username
        }

        # Only do this kind of update if it hasn't failed yet
        $Output += $data
        $desc="$($mac.MACAddress) ( $($bios.serialnumber -replace "-.*") ) $($pc.Model) | $((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))"
        #Set-ADComputer $Computer -Description $desc -verbose
        $Output | select Computername,Enabled,Description,IPaddress,MACaddress,OU,DC,Type,SerialNumber,Manufacturer,Model,RAM,Disk,ProcessorName,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors,Addresswidth,OperatingSystem,InstallDate,LoggedinUser,LastLogonDate | export-csv -Append $file -NoTypeInformation 

    }
    Catch [Exception]
    {
    # Only do this kind of update if create output has failed
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        Add-Content -value "$Computer, $ErrorMessage, skipping to next" $txt
        #Set-ADComputer $Computer -Description $ErrorMessage
            continue
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're building a complex hierarchical object so you'd be better off collecting all the objects then dumping the result as a JSON or XML file. But if you do want a flat string, then you'll have to explicitly format your disk data into a string before adding it to the object you're dumping to CSV. Something like:

```
$diskData = $disk | foreach {
  "[Drive: $($_.DeviceID), Size: $([int]($_.Size/1GB)), FreeSpace: $([int]($_.freespace/1GB)), PercentFree: $([int]($_.freespace/$_.size *100))]"
}
$diskdata = $diskdata -join " "
```